# scatter 3d Chart: is it possible to make values XYZ axis not fixed?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here is my partial code:

```
plotOptions: { scatter: { width: 2, height: 2, depth: 2 } },
            yAxis: { min: -1.50, max: 1.50, title: null },
            xAxis: { min: -1.50, max: 1.50, gridLineWidth: 1 },
            zAxis: { min: -1.50, max: 1.50, showFirstLabel: false },
            legend: { enabled: true }
```

where XYZ have fixed sizes. My data is always different: sometimes max value could be 60, sometime max value = 0.89
It makes 3D graph not useful, if i setup XYZ for 50 MAX and MIN for small data. 
So, my idea is create 3D graph based on data coming on that time.

I am very new to Highlight chart and have no idea how to make charts dynamic. I googled, but could not find solution. Maybe, anyone has idea?

Comment: You can just remove `min` and `max` and the graph will scale automatically. http://jsfiddle.net/xuw39qc1/

Comment: Magic! It works. Thanks!